# Shipping methods like FEDEX/USPS are showing exception"This shipping method is not available. Please specify the zip code."

Tags: magento2, shipping, dhl

While working with Magento2 shipping methods like DHL/FEDEX/USPS on checkout its throwing exception "This shipping method is not available. Please specify the zip code."

Comment: I think the error message is pretty self-explanatory. Did you enter the zip code?

Comment: yes i have added it still giving error.